# Getting a "no viable overloaded operator[] error when trying to return an object from a vector

Tags: c++

I am working on making a small text-based game, and am currently stuck trying to build a function that passes a string, which is the name of a weapon, and returns that weapon object from a vector. Here are the relevant functions:

```
//define weapons like this
Weapon* flimsyDagger = Weapon* (3, "Flimsy Dagger", 17, 4.0);

//store weapons in this vector, which stores all of the stats of each weapon
void Weapon::fillWeaponVector() {
    allWeapons.push_back(flimsyDagger);
}

//use this function to return the weapon by passing its name as it was defined (e.g. 'flimsyDagger') and return all stats
Weapon* Weapon::getWeaponStats(std::string weaponName) {
    return allWeapons[weaponName];
}
```

The error is occurring at the first square brace in the line `return allWeapons[weaponName];`. I have looked everywhere for a solution and haven't found anything that quite fits my situation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would it be better to use a `std::map<std::string, Weapon*>`?  Otherwise, you probably want `find`.

Comment: `Weapon* (3, "Flimsy Dagger", 17, 4.0)` looks like a syntax error to me.

Comment: There would be no viable overload if `allWeapons` is a `std::vector`, the index operator only takes an integral type for them, just like an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claim that you're using a vector, but nothing in the code you've posted indicates that `allWeapons` is in fact a vector.

If it is, you can't index a vector with a text string - indices for vectors must be integers.  As @Eljay suggests, using a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) may be more appropriate.  This allows you to look up the objects you store using a non-numeric key.